# PHP exit with status 1 on service

Tags: php, linux, systemd

My first adventure in to the world of linux services, and I am having a bad time. I have the following script:

```
[Unit]
Description=PHP MQTT Service


[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
TimeoutSec=0
PIDFile=/var/run/php_app_mqtt.pid
ExecStart=/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php -f xyz.xx/subtest.php

StandardOutput=/var/log/myphpdaemon.log
StandardError=/var/log/myphpdaemon.log


KillMode=process


Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I manually run the script from CLI, it works just fine, but when I run it from the service I get this:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mqttdaemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-11-10 20:51:06 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 185754 ExecStart=/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php -f xyz.xx/subtest.php (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 185754 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

This is from me manually starting the service.
I am out of clues, anyone who has an idea of the issue?

Thanks!

EDIT: No logs are created on the specified location

Comment: What's the return value of the script?  `php -f .../subtest.php ; echo $?`. It's returned via a call to `exit $something;`

Comment: The script contains a loop that won't stop until i send the CTRL+C command. I dont now how to check if the script returns something, when run by the service. I thought that would be in the logs.